# Adding iAds to Sprite Kit Landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have the following code in my View Controller:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    if (!skView.scene) {
        skView.showsFPS = NO;
        skView.showsNodeCount = NO;
        skView.showsDrawCount = NO;

        // Create and configure the scene.
        SKScene * scene = [MenuScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
       scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

        self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;

        // Present the scene.
        [skView presentScene:scene];
    }
}
```

When I run the application it crashes immediately. I get the following error message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView scene]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I can't use `SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.originalContentView;` because the app is in landscape mode. Is there a way to display iAds in a Landscap Sprite Kit game?

EDIT:

I just added this code to the view controller, but I get the same results..

```
#pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: what does the crash say? what line does it crash? Add an exception breakpoint if the reported line is in main(). How are you actually adding the ad banner view (merely enabling the ability to display ads isn't enough)?

Comment: I added the error message to my post. Unfortunately I have no idea how to add the ad banner view. This works in a demo app I have but it's portrait.

Comment: I just edited my post with the code that I think should add the ad to the view, but I get the same results..

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Do you have any idea what I could be doing wrong? I tried this exact code in a new portrait project, and it works fine..

Comment: we've had "-[UIView scene]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" concerning iAd multiple times recently, please search for that. Short answer: the view controller's view isn't a SKView as it should be, it's the iAd banner view which doesn't have the scene method. I don't know why but for some reason this seems to be a common error setting the iAd view as the Sprite Kit view controller's view.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I removed `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;` and dragged the ad on to the storyboard. Now it works. Still has the size of a portrait ad, which I would like to be the full witdth, but it's something.. Thanks

Comment: You have basically done wit the storyboard what I did in my answer, except I did it via code. In my answer you can see that I adjust the adView's frame to get the proper dimensions for the ad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this issue and solved it via creating an `ABBannerView` property and adding that as a subView.

In my ViewController class :

```
adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
adView.delegate = self;
[adView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)]; // set to your screen dimensions
[self.view addSubview:adView];
```

Important to NOT set the `canDisplayBannerAds` property of your view controller.

I believe what is happening is that if you do set the `canDisplayBannerAds` property to true, the view is modified and is no longer compatible with a `SKView`, and no longer has a scene property.

I did have to set the frame, so that the dimensions were correct otherwise it was portrait.

Comment: Could probably use the `initWithFrame` parameter to set the frame as well.

Comment: I sort of got this to work, but it tells me to use `_adView` instead of `adView`. Also how do I make the frame responsive for an iPhone 5 or iPhone 4?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by making it responsive for an iphone 4 or 5. Are you asking how to detect the screen dimensions ?

Comment: I just tested it and it actually works fine on both the iPhone 5 and iPhone 4 resolutions. Do you know how to hide the ad when there is no content for it? Like I used to have in my post?

Comment: It's best to ask questions one at a time, each with it's own post. Otherwise there are answers to important questions hidden in long comment trails. Ad is displayed in landscape mode, I'd say that is question answered and best to start another for your next question.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this without having to manually configure the ad banner. You do still have to use the original content view, but making it work correctly is just a matter of putting everything together in the right stages of the view controller's life cycle. All you have to do is enable canDisplayBannerAds: in awakeFromNib. Then set the SKView you create to either the view controller's view or originalContentView depending on the existence of the original content view.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    [self setCanDisplayBannerAds:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    SKView *skView = nil;

    if (self.originalContentView) {
        skView = (SKView *)self.originalContentView;
    }else{
        skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    }

    [skView setShowsDrawCount:YES];
    [skView setShowsFPS:YES];
    [skView setShowsNodeCount:YES];

    SKScene *scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    [scene setScaleMode:SKSceneScaleModeFill];

    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers works for me. Below code is tested in iOS 7 and 8 and works just fine.

Add below lines in header file

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface GameViewController : UIViewController<ADBannerViewDelegate>{

    //iAd
    ADBannerView *adView;

}
```

In Implementation file .m add below code

```
#import "GameViewController.h"
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation GameViewController

-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    SKView *skView;

    if (self.originalContentView) {

        skView = (SKView *)self.originalContentView;

    }

    if (!skView.scene) {

        //[skView setShowsDrawCount:YES];
        //[skView setShowsFPS:YES];
        //[skView setShowsNodeCount:YES];

        //Improve Performance
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;

        GameScene *scene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
        [scene setScaleMode:SKSceneScaleModeFill];

        [skView presentScene:scene];

    }

}

- (void)awakeFromNib{

    [super awakeFromNib];

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    adView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, adView.frame.size.height);
    adView.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:adView];
}

//iAd
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {

    [adView setAlpha:1.0];
    NSLog(@"Show Ad");

}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [adView setAlpha:0];
    NSLog(@"Hide Ad");

}

//

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}

-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{

    return YES;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

@end
```